# CSV file showing incorrect values from numpy array? (TRUE instead of True, FALSE instead of False)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
y_pred=y_pred.astype('|S5')
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
  if y_pred[i]==b"1":
    y_pred[i]="True"
  elif y_pred[i]==b"0":
    y_pred[i]="False"
y_pred=y_pred.astype(str)

print(y_pred)

combined_data = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': df2['PassengerId'], 'Transported': y_pred})
combined_data.to_csv('predictions_logistic.csv', index=False)
```

Output is:
['True' 'True' 'True' ... 'True' 'True' 'False']

However, upon checking the predictions csv file, it shows
[CSV file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJSXF.png)

I am expecting it to be True and False in the csv file (similar to y_pred output given above) not TRUE and FALSE.
Is it interpreting it as boolean? Or is there any problem in the pd.DataFrame or .to_csv method? Please help.

Comment: This sort of operation is often better expressed with `map` and a simple look-up table like `{ "1": "True", ... }`

Comment: better open file in text editor and see what you really have in file. Maybe you use program which automatically display `TRUE` instead of `True` or `1` - so problem can be only this program not your file

Comment: @furas bingo, this is Excel attempting to be helpful (and failing). OP: Excel is horrible with CSV files. Consider a text editor like Notepad(++).

Comment: Stepping back, why does this matter?  If you're doing computations with these, why not leave them as 0 and 1?

Comment: @furas Upon opening it in notepad, it does indeed show "True" instead of "TRUE". Does this simply mean excel isn't showing me the original values?

Comment: @TimRoberts I need this file for a Kaggle submission, which require certain format. All computations are finished at this point, so I am only formatting data.

Answer (score 0):

Opening file with text editor resolved the issue, seems like problem was with excel.

Comment: Yes because Excel attempts to help you by converting the text "True" to the boolean TRUE. If you don't want this behavior, you need to *import* the CSV into Excel and specify that column as text.